# Mod_rewrite remove appending URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am sure this might have been asked before but I've been pulling my hairs for two days with no luck, what I want to do is do a 301 redirect for www.domain1.com/mydesk/anything to www.domain2.com/blogs. So far what I've been able to do is get the /mydesk requests to go to /blogs on domain2 but when ever something is requested like /mydesk/test1/test it goes through so what I would want is know how to remove the appending URL so anything for /mydesk/anything goes to domain2.com/blogs whatsoever.

so http://www.domain1.com/mydesk/whatever 301 http://www.domain2.com/blogs without the appending URL from the requested link.

Thanks.

Comment: What were you using for `/mydesk`?

Comment: Redirect 301 /mydesk http://www.domain2.com/blogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything in the "mydesk" folder to redirect to the same blogs folder on the new domain, you can use this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /mydesk(/.*)? http://www.example.com/blogs
```

If you want to append whatever is after "mydesk" to the new URL (e.g. /mydesk/some-specific-blog -> example.com/blogs/some-specific-blog), you can just append a `$1` to the end of the line, like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /mydesk(/.*)? http://www.example.com/blogs$1
```

Comment: I was trying /mydesk(/.*)$ but this worked like a charm. Thank you so much. You Rock!